# Offsetting long term capital loss in India

Tags: india, capital-loss

How do I offset long term capital loss on equities in India?

Answer (score 1):

Long term capital losses in equity can only be offset against long term capital gains in equity or can be carried forward to next year up to 8 years to offset against gains in those years.